# Dagger 2 does not generate subcomponent implementation

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I've started to setup Dagger 2 and faced a strange issue that looks like a bug to me.

I have 1 main component and 2 subcomponents which I 'plus' in parent component. I use different `scopes` for each subcomponent. The problem is that I can easily do fields injection for the 1st subcomponent but I can't do the same for the second. The injected fields stay `null`s.

Main component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { WalletSaverAppModule.class })
public interface MyAppComponent {
  TrackingComponent plus(TrackingModule module);

  DashboardComponent plus(DashboardModule module);
}
```

1st subcomponent (works well):

```
@PerActivity @Subcomponent(modules = { DashboardModule.class })
public interface DashboardComponent {
  void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

2nd subcomponent (fields injection -> null):

```
@PerService @Subcomponent(modules = { TrackingModule.class })
public interface TrackingComponent {
  void inject(IntentService context);
}
```

How I do fields injection for the 2nd subcomponent:

```
public class TrackingService extends IntentService {
  @Inject CallCase mCallCase;
  @Inject CallModelMapper mCallModelMapper;
  ...

@Override protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
((MyApp) getApplication()).getAppComponent().plus(new TrackingModule(this)).inject(this);
// ---> here the both fields are null
...
```

Objects that I'm injecting:

```
@Singleton public class CallCase {
  private CallRepository mCallRepository;

  @Inject public CallCase(final CallRepository userRepository) {
    mCallRepository = userRepository;
  }

  public Observable<Call> execute() {
    ...
  }
}

@Singleton public class CallModelMapper {
  @Inject CallModelMapper() {
  }

  public CallModel transform(@NonNull final Call callEntity) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Both objects have `@Singleton` scope (as their constructor fields). Could it be a scope conflict?

**--- UPDATE ---**

I've checked the class generated by Dagger2 (`DaggerMyAppComponent`) that I'm using in `MyApp` to build application component. I found the difference between implementations of 1st and 2nd components.

1st:

```
private final class DashboardComponentImpl implements DashboardComponent {
    private final DashboardModule dashboardModule;

    private Provider<DashboardMvp.Presenter> providesPresenterProvider;

    private MembersInjector<MainActivity> mainActivityMembersInjector;

    private DashboardComponentImpl(DashboardModule dashboardModule) {
      this.dashboardModule = Preconditions.checkNotNull(dashboardModule);
      initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {...}

    @Override
    public void inject(MainActivity activity) {...}
  }
```

2nd:

```
private final class TrackingComponentImpl implements TrackingComponent {
    private final TrackingModule trackingModule;

    private TrackingComponentImpl(TrackingModule trackingModule) {
      this.trackingModule = Preconditions.checkNotNull(trackingModule);
      // ---> look, missing call initialize() <---
    }

    @Override
    public void inject(IntentService context) {...}
  }
```

Why Dagger 2 takes different the subcomponents that implemented in the same way? Only one difference I can see is the scope. I would appreciate any inputs about this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you change TrackingComponent's scope to PerActivity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TrackingComponent why are you inject to IntentService. Maybe changing to TrackingService will help

```
void inject(TrackingService context);
```

Comment: +1. See "a note about covariance" on the [`@Component` docs](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html#members-injection-methods): If you write your members-injection method to accept `IntentService`, you'll only inject fields for IntentService and its superclasses, so nothing will happen. If you accept `TrackingService`, Dagger can do its compile-time magic for TrackingServices and the `@Inject` fields there.

Comment: Thanks! Golden eyes ;)